# Should I list a letter in my cv?

Tags: publications, cv

If someone writes a letter to the editor and I write a response, how should I list the response this in my CV?

It *is* peer reviewed but is only a 300 words, so it doesn't seem right to put this under 'journal articles' (though the title starts with "Reply To: ... ", which makes it clear).

Comment: What discipline?

Comment: How does the publisher suggest citing your work?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist science

Comment: @user2768 I've never seen guidance from a publisher beyond the citation that they provide and in this case, it says the citation type is 'article' but on the website and in the instructions for authors the classification is 'matters arising'.

Comment: @abe The citation type is 'article,' so use that. (I don't understand what 'matters arising' means.)

Comment: @user2768 ["Matters arising"](https://www.nature.com/nature/for-authors/matters-arising) is a special name the journal gives to "post-publication commentary"

Comment: @abe Is it specific only to Nature?

Comment: @user2768 I suspect so, but that illustrates the fact that it wouldn't make sense to use the publishers guidance on 'article type' in my CV since it can be journal specific

Answer (score 3):

I put these on my CV as peer-reviewed publications and label them as 'commentary'. I also label other works 'review', 'empirical', etc. as appropriate. The title can also be used to signal the type of work, like "[Title]: Commentary on Zeller et al., 2018".

Answer (score 1):

Rename your "Journal Articles" section to "Publications". Put under "Publications".

Optionally you can have an "Other Work" section where you list less-important stuff. Throw it under there.